# When clicking a tag in the android app clear it in the search box

Tags: feature-request, android-app, tag-search

When composing a question you can type part of a tag to search for it. If you click the tag from the search results it adds it to the list but keeps your search in the textbox.

Given you've just selected the tag you were searching for I think it should clear it ready for the next tag.